# salesforce lightning component not accepting '&' character

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-experience

I have a default attribute of type String in my lightning component. I need set the default value of this attribute as - "/apex/pagename?opr=convert&opptyId=someid'. but it is not accepting the & character. It is showing this error when saved:

> ParseError at [row,col]:[5,95]
>   Message: The reference to entity "opptyId" must end with the ';' delimiter.

I am using sublime text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try Like this** use `&amp;`

```
 <aura:attribute name="text" type="String" Default="/apex/pagename?opr=convert&amp;opptyId=someid" />
```